# Import Error: No module named watson_developer_cloud

Tags: pi-3, python-3

I'm trying to create a program that will send an image to the IBM Watson studio and use that to perform a computer vision image recognition analysis.

Anyways, when I try to run the program, it only gets as far as

```
import picamera
from time import sleep
import random
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import VisualRecognitionV3
```

From there, I get the error `Import Error: No module named watson_developer_cloud`.

I have already installed it using `pip install --upgrade 'watson-developer-cloud>=2.4.1'` from the website itself.

I am also very new to both Raspberry Pi and Python so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on how you tagged your question, you are using Python 3 and therefore need to use pip3 to install the module. You can install it for Python 3 with the following command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade 'watson-developer-cloud>=2.4.1'
```